# How to get event of wordpress's oEmbed object is loaded in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, tinymce, embed

I paste link in WordPress TinyMCE editor like this:
https://gist.github.com/kolesnikof/642ae1317cc23b87977f/

and I get oEmbed object like this: http://prntscr.com/7wlsrz

---

by putting code in functions.php like this:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Usage:
     * Paste a gist link into a blog post or page and it will be embedded eg:
     * https://gist.github.com/2926827
     *
     * If a gist has multiple files you can select one using a url in the following format:
     * https://gist.github.com/2926827?file=embed-gist.php
     */

    wp_embed_register_handler( 'gist', '/https:\/\/gist\.github\.com\/(\d+)(\?file=.*)?/i', 'wp_embed_handler_gist' );

    function wp_embed_handler_gist( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr ) {

        $embed = sprintf(
            '&lt;script src="https://gist.github.com/%1$s.js%2$s"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;',
            esc_attr($matches[1]),
            esc_attr($matches[2])
        );

        return apply_filters( 'embed_gist', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
    }
?>
```

My question: I want highlight oEmbed code, but I don't know event handler  trigger when ajax finish load oEmbed content

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem, but decision isn't elegant:

add script to oEmbed object

```
if ( is_admin() ) $embed .= '<script>window.top.Prism.highlightElement(document.getElementsByTagName(\'pre\')[0]);</script>';
```